# Is there a way to find the list of Files accessed ( CRUD) by a Docker Container over its mounted volume

Tags: docker

I am interested to find the list of files accessed ( create, read, update, delete) by a Docker container over its Mounted volume.

I can use File monitor over volume , would like to know is there any way it can be acheived or metrics extracted while Docker container access the volume and the directories or files present inside.

Volume mapping by -v hostdir:containerdir

Answer (score 1):

On windows you can use [process monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/procmon). On linux you can use [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/).